# Meaning of ‘No shame’ as an independent sentence

Tags: meaning-in-context

I found the following paragraph while reading a book:

> “Paying your rent or mortgage? Not as easy to get around unless moving in with your parents is on the table. No shame.”

When the writer uses ‘No shame’ in this context, what does he intend to convey specifically?

Comment: I doubt that the expression conveys a negative connotation in this case, as he seems to try not to offend the readers.

Comment: Presumably he means "There is nothing to be ashamed of in being in this situation".

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The writer uses the pharse '*No shame.*' as an informal way of saying *There is no shame in this.*

Answer (score -1):

When a sentence is followed by one or more occurrences of "no" and a noun or phrase, the intention is to briefly summarise the fact that some undesirable thing is absent or avoided.

Use an electronic card when travelling on the subway. No waiting. No cash to worry about. No ticket to lose.

Use a plate when eating creamy cakes. No mess on the table.